# Gazebo /clock publish rate

Tags: ros, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo publishes /clock at 10Hz. Can this be increased and how?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25290/gazebo-/clock-publish-rate/) by [fiji3119](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27866/fiji3119/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

`/clock` publishes a message once per every new state, i.e. at 1/[max_step_size](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=physics#physics_max_step_size) Hz. You should rather focus on why your simulation runs so slow than the clock publish rate (did you perhaps tweak max_step_size?).

Nonetheless, if you still want to change the frequency, you can do that with the `/gazebo/pub_clock_frequency` parameter on the parameter server.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fiji3119](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27866/fiji3119/) on 2020-06-09**:
I am using default value i.e max_step_size = 0.001 but when I run `ros2 topic hz /clock`, I get avg 10Hz. Shouldn't I expect 1000hz?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-06-09**:
So, things are different in ROS2. It seems that /clock indeed publishes at 10 Hz. You can find the answer to your question [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki/ROS-2-Migration:-ROS-Clocks-and-sim-time#clock-rate).

**Comment by [fiji3119](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/27866/fiji3119/) on 2020-06-10**:
Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!